# objective c - @property with variable definition, what should happen?

Tags: objective-c, variables, properties

Lets say I have the following object definition (notice the mistake):

```
@interface User : NSObject {
    NSString* pid;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* publicId;

@end
```

Notice the mistake? I defined pid, but wrote publicId under property.

This does not cause any compiler errors (I use XCode 4 for iOS) and actually seems to work at most cases (I can set and get public Id although it is not defined in the object!). If I try to imagine what @property and @synthesize do, I can't seem to get any idea how this does not create compiler errors!

Why is does this seem to work? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what platform you're targetting, `publicId` is backed by a dynamically generated instance variable. `pid` is not used. (This is true for 64-bit Mac OS X and for iOS; for 32-bit Mac OS X, this should compile with warnings or errors indicating the incompleteness of your class.)

Comment: Thanks! Dynamically - during runtime or during compile time?

Comment: @Yoav Compile time. With Obj-C 2.0 you no longer need anything between the curly braces in your interface declaration. When Interface Builder generates them for me in Xcode 4 (control-dragging from a control to the interface file to auto-generate the property, synthesize, set to nil, and release code) I immediately delete them: no need to keep an unnecessary line of code in sync when refactoring, etc.